# Integration with JIB Gradle cause compilation error

Tags: java, gradle, jib

Tring to integrate with JIB (Containerize your Gradle Java project) with my Java project.

Following this documentation: https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/tree/master/jib-gradle-plugin

Added the following to my project:

```
dependencies {
  classpath("gradle.plugin.com.google.cloud.tools:jib-gradle-plugin:3.1.4")
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.cloud.tools.jib'
jib.to.image = 'my-docker-local/my-app'
```

Gradle version is: 5.6.4

The compilation with "./gradlew" build is working fine. but, when
excecuting "gradle jib" getting the following error:

> gradle jib  To honour the JVM settings for this build a single-use
> Daemon process will be forked. See
> https://docs.gradle.org/7.2/userguide/gradle_daemon.html#sec:disabling_the_daemon.
> Daemon will be stopped at the end of the build
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - Where: Build file '/Users/igorgumush/dev/java11/my-service/build.gradle' line: 139
> - What went wrong: A problem occurred evaluating root project 'my-service'.
>
> Could not find method compile() for arguments [org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web,
> build_9nl2gys0kuhc8m4mdlq51u41r$_run_closure4$_closure24@6ea6088b] on
> object of type
> org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
>
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it
> incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

Comment: would you mind providing build.gradle file instead try upgrading the gradle version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the solution was very simple.
I used:

```
./gradlew jib
```

instead of

```
grade jib
```